# Index out of bound in painterResource() when updating BottomNavigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently getting an index out of bound which I can't figure out why...

Following situation:
Sometimes I update my compose bottom navigation to add an item or to change tint color etc. When the app is running and the update is happening it works. But when i close the app and it starts to initialize the navigation with the new state I get an index out of bound exception on the painterResource...

Would be nice if anyone has a hint for me. Another thing to add is i wire the compose currently to xml but i can't see a problem with that.

Thanks in advance

```
BottomNavigation(
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
) {
    navigation.navigationItems.forEach { navigationItem ->
        val isSelected = selectedItem == navigationItem.destination
        val iconResId =
            if (isSelected) navigationItem.selectedIconRes else navigationItem.iconRes

        val hasBadge = badges.contains(navigationItem.destination)
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = {
                if (hasBadge) {
                    BadgedBox(
                        modifier = Modifier.background(badgeBackgroundColor),
                        badge = { Badge(backgroundColor = badgeColor) }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            painterResource(iconResId),
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    Icon(
                        painterResource(iconResId),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            },
            selected = isSelected,
            onClick = { onItemSelected(navigationItem.destination) },
            alwaysShowLabel = true,
            selectedContentColor = selectedTintColor,
            unselectedContentColor = tintColor
        )
    }
}
```

Update:
I found now out why it happens but it’s still strange. The drawable itself produced somehow that error. After putting a different one there it worked all the time. The question is why did it not work after restarting the app but when running on the dynamic change… I have no idea…

Update 2:
After the dynamic change there are artifacts happening within the icons… For example 3rd icon has artifacts of 4th etc. What could cause that? Any idea?

Comment: Can you add code from where you call this? Do you modify your list in some way inside onCreate method?

Comment: Hi, I put some updates up there. Found a different problem now…